# Best laptop for running XP on

Tags: laptop, windows

I need a laptop that can support windows XP 64 bit, I need 16gb of ram minimum and a good Intel processor. The WiFi card HAS to be reliable and not keep disconnecting

I know that drivers for modern hardware can be a problem as vendors don't bother to support XP anymore.

I have a dell inspiron e5200 right now, it is hopeless and I've had enough.
I have a high end HP laptop, that doesn't support XP very well. and it's also hopeless regardless of what I put on it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "vendors don't bother to support XP" - That's because end of life was April 8, 2014

Comment: I think the lenovo 530 might well be possible, the nividia quatro 2000M has support for XP and the sata controller might, it also has 20 hours of battery life with a secondary battery. I'll keep the topic open still

Comment: Windows XP was phased out of support Apr 8 '14. That's why vendors don't support it - because Microsoft doesn't. It's not secure, it's not modern. There's no good reason *to* support it.

Comment: Are there any specific reasons you need XP? (legacy apps critical to business, etc)

Comment: I've used the OS for over 14 years and have only once got a virus (and even then I was to blame) since I was unsure if it was safe but clicked it anyway. There is no reason to suddenly care that its not a secure OS, it always has been and nobody really cared then cause it was so popular. This is just the media causing controversy over what is a threat but just does not happnen.

Comment: Would you be willing to run a VM for your specific application and than Windows 7/10 for any other day to day use? If you are willing, than get anything you want and just run VirtualBox or VMWare and you are good to go. This is what I do when I need a specific OS for a specific reason

Comment: a vm isnt possible cause I need utilize all of the RAM  and I don't like windows vista 7 8 or 10 as i've tried them before as a main OS.

Comment: @A_User XP is EoS, and no longer receiving updates, because Microsoft has determined it impractical to support it any longer. It's like using Internet Explorer 6. I do advise you to try other alternatives, such as lubuntu (which has the advantage of even lower memory overhead), if you're not especially attached to any software application specific to windows.

Comment: Microsoft has nothing to do with third party hardware driver support, microsoft dont make those sort of drivers

Comment: @A_User Even so, Microsoft does provide security updates, and 3rd party vendors could find XP impractical to support for the same reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should take a look at used workstation laptops made just before the XP support dropped off, maybe circa-2013. Since you are already familiar with high-end HP, I suggest looking for a used 8570w or 8770w. There appears to be a full set of 64bit XP drivers available ([8570w - Windows XP 64bit drivers](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=5257503&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=2002)). There are dual core and quad core variants of this laptop, with the dual core supporting 16gb of memory and the quad supporting 32gb. The wireless card is an Intel Ultimate-N 6300 which does have a Windows XP 64bit dirver. The supported i5 and i7 processors are 3rd generation / Ivy bridge, but you will still have much better performance versus the Dell Inspiron you mentioned.